# Play framework, Scala and IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I am trying to make a play project using IntelliJ14 Community editions.
I get the following errors when importing play libraries:

```
    Error:(3, 8) not found: object play
    import play.api._
           ^
    Error:(4, 8) not found: object play
    import play.api.mvc._
           ^
    Error:(5, 8) not found: object play
    import play.api.data._
           ^
    Error:(6, 8) not found: object play
    import play.api.data.Forms._
           ^
    Error:(7, 8) not found: object play
    import play.api.data._
           ^
    Error:(9, 8) not found: object anorm
    import anorm._
           ^
    Error:(10, 8) not found: object anorm
    import anorm.SqlParser._
           ^
    Error:(11, 8) not found: object play
    import play.api.db._
           ^
    Error:(12, 8) not found: object play
    import play.api.Play.current
       ^
```

My plugins.sbt is defined as:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.8")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % Option(System.getProperty("play.version")).getOrElse("2.0"))
```

What am I doing wrong here? I would expect I should be able to import play libs if I have defined the plug-in in the plugins.sbt file? Kindly let me know.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Try importing the project in IntelliJ Idea , rather than opening it. Run activator idea in the project directory it may solve the problem.

Comment: How do you specify libraryDependencies? Could you show your build.sbt?

Comment: attached is my build.sbt                                                                                                    name := """play-scala-app"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.3.4"

)

Answer (score 1):

you might be using free version of IntelliJ Idea so it doesn't give you inbuilt feature to create play application. Rater than create direct project into IntelliJ use activator to create it.

Install activator/Scala in your machine, set PATH system variable for activator/scala.

GOTO command prompt and set folder path where you want to create Play projecr, run "activator new" command, it will ask for type of project, choose Play with scala/java application.

Now after done with this open/import your project into IntelliJ Idea, it will again ask for **options Auto import and download sources.**, choose these options.

After importing project I don't think you will get an issue.

Comment: Yes, Community Edition doesn't support Play: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html, but the project should at least compile :)

Comment: I know it doesn't make any problem on compilation. But when you are configuring so many things manually chances are high for errors.

Comment: I created application using activator then imported into intelliJ. this is how I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've received these import errors when running `sbt` from the wrong base directory.

Double check that you're running `sbt` from its project root.